# Golang unexpected EOF with http.Get and http.ServeFile

Tags: go

I have a server which serves a large file (~80MB) and a client within a unit test which downloads this file. The client is getting an "Unexpected EOF" error after ~40MB. I can download this file without issue through any browser, and there does not appear to be an issue with the content (an MPEG2 TS video).

Server:

```
func ServeFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // CORS
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,OPTIONS")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    // Content-related headers
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "filename=video.ts")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "video/mp2t")
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "video.ts")
}
```

Client:

```
url := "http://localhost:8080/video.ts"
response, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err)
}
defer response.Body.Close()
if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
    log.Error(response.StatusCode)
}
f, err := os.Create("video.ts")
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err)
}
defer f.Close()
_, err := io.Copy(f, response.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err)
}
```

Given that I can download the full file via a browser, my guess is that the issue is with the client. However, I have downloaded larger files than this via the same combination of `http.Get` and `io.Copy`, so I'm not sure why I'm experiencing this issue when I serve the file myself via Go.

Comment: for the output - can you try again with   `os.Create(os.DevNull)` and see if its any different

Comment: Same result, unexpected EOF after about 40MB

Comment: would you mind to share the file?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot due to the contents of the file, but I have tried multiple different ts files and the result has been the same. May be worth noting I concatenate multiple 5-second ts files to get video.ts, then after this process has finished I serve the completed file. Same issue occurs if I simply try to serve a pre-completed video.ts however.

Comment: Could you share the full stack trace?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get this from the client-side error, which only seems to have "Unexpected EOF". The server side does not appear to have any error. However, I have found that when using wget, I receive "Connection closed. Retrying." at the same point. This occurs several times until the full file is downloaded. In the server, the ServeFile function appears to "complete" each time the connection is closed, and is begun each time the connection is retried. So the issue must be in ServeFile.

Comment: Additionally, the response is "206: Partial Content". I am guessing I just need a more sophisticated client in my reader to handle the partial content.

Comment: On further investigation I believe wget is issuing the range requests, which the server is handling. I can add a similar scheme for my client, but AFAIK this is unexpected behavior for ServeFile. Does anyone know why the server seems to terminate early when serving large files?